# How to maintain a local mirror of Drupal.org projects?

Tags: git, drupal, offline, mirroring

Now that Drupal.org has [switched to using Git](http://drupal.org/node/1013552), is there an easy way to maintain an up-to-date mirror of a selected subset (or even all) of the core and contrib projects locally? Or would that be discouraged because of the strain it would put on the drupal.org infrastructure?

I realize I can clone individual projects, but I'd like a mirror that automatically pulls updates periodically. It would be nice to have projects available in the event of an outage, plus it would make it easier to develop when offline.

Comment: I really don't think it'd be a problem to mirror everything. The git protocol is fairly efficient and won't result in much overhead. Get a list of projects and clone each project into a local directory, then setup a cronjob to run `git pull` in each of those folders every week or so.

Comment: I agree with Alex, a simple cronjob would do the trick here.

Comment: @Alex Vidal if you convert that from a comment to an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your technical question about mirroring the projects, here's what I would do:

- Get a list of all of the projects (since git.drupal.org doesn't have a project list)
- Create a directory to hold all of the mirrors (ie, ~/projects/drupal-mirror/)
- For each project, run `git clone git://git.drupal.org/project/<project>.git <project>`
- Setup a cronjob to run `git pull` for each one of those projects, every week or so.

For your local development, you can clone your local mirror to another directory.

In regards to whether or not it's the polite way to do it, I suppose only the Drupal community can answer that. What I can say, though, is that the git protocol is fairly efficient and won't result in much overhead to maintain your mirrors. If you want to stagger your pulls, you could run the `git pull` for each project in a staggered fashion, so you're not hitting all of them one after the other every week.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty python script does exactly this.

https://github.com/olragon/drupalmirror